# Is it possible changing the result columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table  *MyTable* with 6 columns:
When I write : select * from MyTable I get this result

> NAME | LAST_NAME | FIRST_NAME | AGE | SALARY | ID

what I want is to change their order, I want for ID to be at the first NOT at lat

example : when i write the query select * from MyTable I want the result to be like this:

> ID | NAME | LAST_NAME | FIRST_NAME | AGE | SALARY

why do I want this ?: This table has a procedure that takes what I insert and with a parser I create another query for them.
example: if I insert id =1 and name = stack and last_name =over the parser will make it in such way:
 insert into mytable values (1,'stack','over') ( this a simple example my parser is complicated)
so you will ask your self why I need that at the first place?
because I have 20+ developer that consider ID is at the first. 
It all started when I was trying to modify the column ID, so I had to drop it and recreate the column again and add constraints and change NULL to NOT NULL, before dropping it I put the data in a temporary column, in such way I didn't lost the data. But one thing i didn't see is column orders.
okay I can simply tell the developers about that change, but if i did that i will be asked a lot of questions, how i did that and why. I don't want anyone to know that (if its possible)

one of the solution in my mind is creating a new table with the correct rows. but procedures, triggers will be droped and I have to add them again for that table, and i am afraid I encounter new problems with re-creating the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `*`, specify the columns in the order you want, like:

```
select ID, NAME, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, AGE, SALARY  from MyTable
```

If you must reorder the columns create a view:

```
create view MyView as
  select ID, NAME, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, AGE, SALARY  from MyTable
```

so that `select * from MyView` will return what you want.

`*` is just a convenient shortcut. Since it's not explicit it can cause errors too easily when columns are added or removed in a table. Using it in production code is not good.

Do not create another table, that's way too complicated.

Comment: as i mentioned in my long question , the order is for developers and i dont want them to know i droped the columns

Comment: @moudiz: then you are stuck. the developers shouldn't be using * anyway.

Comment: @moudiz: they **will** notice if there is any reference to the column in the code. You are creating an un-maintainable system this way. Simply communicate the change in DB structure and make the necessary changes in the code. It's a **very** bad habit to rely on column ordering in an INSERT statement anyway. The columns should always be listed explicitely e.g. `insert into foo (col1, col2) values (1,2)`

Comment: @moudiz: +1 for a_horse_with_no_name. your change was not the problem, the developers' sloppy sql is the problem.